# How can I provide single credential (login) for multiple Zoho Creator cloud data connection in PowerBI?

Tags: cloud, powerbi-desktop, credentials, zoho, zoho-deluge

I am fetching multiple Zoho Creator reports by using built-in cloud data connection in one single PowerBI file.

There are almost 45 separate Zoho creator tables(connections) inside the PowerBI file. When I trigger data refresh, PowerBI asks for my credentials for each datasource separately, even though the credentials are the same for all data sources.

Is there a better way to provide my Zoho Creator credentials once for multiple data source?

I tried to contact Zoho creator for allowing 3rd party connections after one successfull authentication but no result so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.